# How can I set the colour of the UINavigationItem in the UINavigationController added via storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a setup in which I am using `storyboards` to create the structure of my app. I make use of a `UINavigationController`, however I want to change the colour of the `UINavigationItem` from the default blue that apple assigns. Please can someone advise on where to do this? I looked in `IB` but the option is not shown. I have also considered setting it in one of my classes however I'm not sure where, since the `UINavigationController` is not initialized manually.

Please can someone offer some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UIAppearance`, as following

in your appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add the following line

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

This will change the color of the navigation bar to green